# BigInt Multiplication w/ int arrays

Tags: c++, bigint

I'm making a `BigInt` class in C++ as an exercise. I'm currently working on the multiplication functionality. My `BigInt`'s are represented as a fixed length (that is very big) `int[]`, with each entry being a digit of the number entered.

So, `BigInt = 324`, will result in `[0,0,0,..,3,2,4]`.

I'm currently trying to multiply using this code:

```
// multiplication
BigInt BigInt::operator*(BigInt const& other) const {
  BigInt a = *this;
  BigInt b = other;
  cout << a << b << endl;
  BigInt product = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
    int carry = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++){
      product.digits[arraySize - (j + i)] += (carry + (a.digits[j] * b.digits[i]));
      carry = (product.digits[arraySize - (j + i)] / 10);
      product.digits[arraySize - (j + i)] = (product.digits[arraySize - (j + i)] % 10);
    }
    product.digits[arraySize - i] += carry;
  }
  return product;
}
```

My answer keeps returning 0. For example, `2 * 2 = 0`.

Comment: I haven't traced your algorithm very far, but you have some indexing irregularities. (Multiply from least-significant digit to most for _all_ operands.) Also, a and b are unnecessary copies of your source operands.

Comment: it'd be helpful to show BigInt class definition and constructor

Answer (score 1):

It is not sure that this will fix your program, but you have `Undefined Behavior` because of this:

```
product.digits[arraySize - (j + i)]
```

This index `arraySize - (j + i)` becomes negative when `i + j > arraySize`, which will obviously occur in your loop.

Basically, when multiplying two numbers with n digits, the result may be as wide as 2n digits. Since you encode all your numbers on fixed length `arraySize`, you have to take measures to avoid out of bound.

A simple test `if(i+j) <= arraySize` could do, or by changing the second loop:

```
 for(int j = 0; j < arraySize - i; j++)
```

Alternatively, it would be better to use `std::vector` as the internal representation of your BigInt. It can be sized dynamically to fit your result beforehand.

It is not completely sure that this will fix completely your code, but it has to be fixed, before proceeding with the debugging. It will be easier after removing the UB. Here I approve @Dúthomhas's note that your indexing through the arrays seems obviously irregular... You go from right to left with the result, while from left to right with the inputs...